# Successfully deploying and then subsequently undeploying a seam project from jboss server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, seam

I am using Eclipse Helios 3.6, JBoss Tools (the latest version) and JBossAS 5.1. I have a project that was working fine before. For some reason, I restarted my JBoss and the project gets deployed and almost immediately gets undeployed. It does this continuously. This is not the first time a project am working on is behaving like this.

From what I can see, there are no errors in my code, please could someone tell me how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had this problem I've noticed that a file from eclipse, ended with *.spdia was causing this issue.

You can manually delete it or you can modify your ant script to not deploy it again.

For my case:

```
<copy todir="${war.deploy.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${war.dir}">
             <exclude name="**/*.spdia"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cristian. I would never have figured that out